# How to Show  contact photo in my application?

Tags: android

I want to show image of contacts(form contact list) in my application. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) { 
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id); 
InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
 if (input == null) {  
  return null;    
 }
 return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

Comment: How did you set this to an imageview?

Comment: convert bitmap to drawable set it

Answer (score 0):

Examine the code shown on this page and your problem should be solved:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/retrieving-contact-information-name-number-and-profile-picture/

Comment: Yes, it is working for me but I don't won't to use decrypted API's.